# Event based input files management system

Tags: c#, .net, generics, wpf, reflection

I'm currently making a system that can accept different sorts of files and some classes are interested only in specific types of files, while some don't discriminate at all.

**Note**

- *Type of file* isn't necessarily a difference in the extension of a file, but rather how they function, e.g music files have duration, but not only 1 extension, so every file that has duration only is considered a Music File regardless of their extension.

I decided to go for an event based approach because there might be no consumers and there might be many and I don't really want to introduce any dependencies in the notifier classes or clutter them with unnecessary logic.

To simplify the job of the notifier I wrote a helper class - `ManagerHelper`, this avoids the need of filtering the input in every class and also provides extendability in case a new file type is added in the system which would otherwise require a change in every notifier class.

This is the current diagram of how the classes operate:

[image]

Simple enough structure and it does the job.

### IFileInformation

---

All file types inherit a common interface with the most basic information a file can have:

```
public interface IFileInformation
{
    string FileName { get; }
    FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    Uri Uri { get; }
}
```

### FileInformation

---

The basic implementation of the interface is `FileInformation`, it's used primarily for files such as text documents:

```
public class FileInformation : IFileInformation
{
    public string FileName { get; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    public Uri Uri { get; }

    public FileInformation(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
        }
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileInfo.Name);
        Uri = new Uri(FileInfo.FullName);
    }

    public FileInformation(Uri fileUri)
        : this(fileUri.OriginalString)
    {
    }
}
```

### MediaFileInformation

---

For media files we have `MediaFileInformation`, it has a `TimeSpan FileLength` property, and a property + `DependencyProperty` for the state of the file - playing/not playing:

```
public class MediaFileInformation : DependencyObject, IFileInformation, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimeSpan FileLength { get; }
    public string FileName { get; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    public Uri Uri { get; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsPlaying), typeof(bool), typeof(MediaFileInformation),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MediaFileInformation(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
        }
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileInfo.Name);
        FileLength = FileInfo.GetFileDuration();
        Uri = new Uri(FileInfo.FullName);
    }

    public MediaFileInformation(Uri fileUri)
        : this(fileUri.OriginalString)
    {
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

### Manager

---

There is actually a single generic static class - `Manager<TFileInformation>`. It contains a single event, along with few overloads of the same method to request a new file update:

```
public static class Manager<TFileInformation>
    where TFileInformation : IFileInformation
{
    public static event EventHandler<ManagerEventArgs<TFileInformation>> NewRequest;

    public static void Request(IEnumerable<TFileInformation> selectedFiles)
    {
        Request(new ManagerEventArgs<TFileInformation>(selectedFiles));
    }

    public static void Request(ManagerEventArgs<TFileInformation> args)
    {
        OnNewRequest(args);
    }

    private static void Request(IEnumerable<object> selectedFiles)
    {
        Request(selectedFiles.Cast<TFileInformation>());
    }

    private static void OnNewRequest(ManagerEventArgs<TFileInformation> args)
    {
        NewRequest?.Invoke(typeof(Manager<TFileInformation>), args);
    }
}
```

### ManagerHelper

---

As illustrated in the diagram, this class servers as a mediator, which notifies each `Manager`, along with the appropriate information, that they must invoke their respective event. If you've already noticed, there is an odd `private` method inside the `Manager` class, it's used here, because of problems I encountered while trying to cast the generic type argument of `IEnumerable<object>` to a specific implementation of the `IFileInformation`.

The only solution I came up with, which keeps the type safety of the `Manager` class, was to make a private method and access that only through reflection and allow the `Manager` class to cast the `IEnumerable<object>` to the appropriate `IEnumerable<TFileInformation>`.

```
public static class ManagerHelper
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<IEnumerable<object>>> _newRequests;

    static ManagerHelper()
    {
        var fileInformations = typeof(IFileInformation).GetDerivedTypesFor(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        _newRequests = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IEnumerable<object>>>();
        foreach (var information in fileInformations)
        {
            var instance = typeof(Manager<>).MakeGenericType(information);
            var methodInfo = instance.GetMethod("Request", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            _newRequests.Add(information, enumerable => methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { enumerable }));
        }
    }

    public static void Request(IEnumerable<IFileInformation> selectedFiles)
    {
        Request(new ManagerEventArgs<IFileInformation>(selectedFiles));
    }

    public static void Request(ManagerEventArgs<IFileInformation> args)
    {
        var typeGroups = args.SelectedFiles.GroupBy(information => information.GetType());
        foreach (var typeGroup in typeGroups)
        {
            _newRequests[typeGroup.Key].Invoke(typeGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

### ManagerEventArgs

---

```
public class ManagerEventArgs<TFileInformation>
    where TFileInformation : IFileInformation
{
    public IEnumerable<TFileInformation> SelectedFiles { get; }

    public ManagerEventArgs(IEnumerable<TFileInformation> selectedFiles)
    {
        SelectedFiles = selectedFiles ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectedFiles));
    }
}
```

### Usage

---

Now if you want to receive notification when a new file of type X is added you just do:

```
Manager<X>.NewRequest+=...
```

It's also really simple to send a collection of different types of files for the notifier:

```
ManagerHelper.Request(files)
```

In case you only want to send a filtered bunch of files you can also do:

```
Manager<X>.Request(files.OfType<X>());
```

---

What are you thoughts? Are there any flaws? Anything I can improve on? Maybe you have a better alternative solution?

I personally feel that the naming could be improved and maybe there is a better way of accessing the public method of the `Manager` instead of making a private one just for this use.

If you need any extra information feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: Your `ManagerHelper` isn't a helper. It's a *file router*.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate code in `FileInformation` and `MediaFileInformation`

`MediaFileInformation` should inherit from `FileInformation` to eliminate the duplicate code.  In the ctor just call `base`

```
public class FileInformation
{
    public string FileName { get; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    public Uri Uri { get; }

    public FileInformation(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
        }
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileInfo.Name);
        Uri = new Uri(FileInfo.FullName);
    }

    public FileInformation(Uri fileUri)
        : this(fileUri.OriginalString)
    {
    }
}
public class MediaFileInformation : FileInformation
{
    public TimeSpan FileLength { get; }
    public MediaFileInformation(string filePath)
        : base(filePath)
    {
        FileLength = FileInfo.GetFileDuration();
    }

    public MediaFileInformation(Uri fileUri)
        : base(fileUri)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, take another look at the class MediaFileInformation.

Comment: Please take a look at duplicate code is eliminate.  Sorry if this is not helpful.

Comment: The DependencyProperty is missing

Comment: You cannot add it?

Comment: If you can I'd be more than happy to incorporate your advice in my project

Comment: Add DependencyObject to the base class FileInformation.  I just tested and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't want FileInformation to be a DependencyObject

Comment: OK then don't use this